# Database migrations out of sync on azure

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-2.0

It seems like none of my new db migrations are applying because my db hosted on azure is out of sync with my localhost.

I went into the __EFMigrationsHistory and deleted the entry that was deleted on localhost. However, it doesn't apply the new ones. Is there a way I can use the scm debugger to manually do a `dotnet ef database update`?

I looked at my __EFMigrationsHistory table and its definitely out of sync. I deleted the entries that no longer have a migration file for. But can I just fill in new entries for ones I do have migration files for? I can't seem to run `dotnet ef database updat`

Comment: You can try to go to `<yourwebapp>.scm.azurewebsites.net` and go to `Debug console` > `CMD`. Not sure if you can run migrations from there, but I _was_ able to run `dotnet --version`

Comment: Please examine the Event Log (Windows OS) entries on the box where you installed the SQL Data Sync Agent. Share with us what you find on Event Viewer->Applications and Services Logs->SQL Azure Data Sync Preview or Event Viewer->Applications and Services Logs->Data Sync Service.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up updating the connection string in my applicationSettings in visual studio code. Then I manually reverted and applied my new ef migrations through the terminal.